# JQuery file upload disable not image preview

Tags: yii2, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I use yii2 and blueimp jQuery File Upload Plugin for upload multiple files at my site.
How I can disable preview for not image files?

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the [Project website on github](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-restrict-the-file-selection-dialog-to-show-only-specific-file-types):

> You can use the accept attribute of the file input field to limit the file type  selection, though this seems to be supported only on Google Chrome and Opera.
>   An example limiting files to PNG images:

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" accept="image/png" multiple>
```

> Note that this will not limit files added by drag&drop and is not supported across all browsers.

If you must upload files with a specific extension you can restric the upload.